# Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (6)

Tags: meteor, html5-appcache

I'm using the App Cache package for MeteorJS and I'm getting the following error *Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (6)* I have no idea what's casing it has anyone else had this issue?

Really not sure what's going, my app gets stuck and does not render certain elements but on the other had I can still see my navigation for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar experience. It was caused by an **onBeforeAction** in my route. Specifically it was **Meteor.loggingIn()** which appears to return *true* if the application is offline. To solve it I simply added **!Meteor.status().connected** to the condition.

In my case I had several **Router.onBeforeAction** to check if the user was allowed to view a specific route.

Also, make sure you're not waiting for any publications that isn't available offline. You can use [ground:db](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) to store collections in local storage.